# Counter for a Concurrent Server

Tags: java, concurrency, client-server

I have a concurrent server where a user chooses an option to display.  Every time any option is selected a counter increments displaying only the total for all options selected.  Individual counters are NOT required for different options; only total is required.

After referencing the JAVA API the most sensible method appeared to be using atomic integers and everything worked perfectly as expected.

I produced the following:

ServerProtocol.java

```
public class ServerProtocol {

private static final int ANOTHER = 2;
private static final int OPTIONS = 3;

case OPTIONS:
    if (theInput.equals("1")) {
        theOutput = "computer program description here  -- Another? Y or N";

        DownloadCounter counter = new DownloadCounter();
        counter.incrementCount();
        System.out.println(counter);

        TrackDownloads clientDetails = new TrackDownloads();
        clientDetails.trackLocalhostAddress();
        state = ANOTHER;
case ANOTHER:
```

DownloadCounter.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class DownloadCounter {

    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void incrementCount() {
        count.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Total Downloads =" + count;
    }
}
```

The problem being that my lecturer has turned around and said I cant use atomic integers!

They have supplied me with some code that I must include in my project.  That is:

```
 int tmp = yourCounter;
     try {
         Thread.sleep(5000);
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
         System.out.println("sleep interrupted");
     }
  yourCounter = tmp + 1;
```

The problem is I don't seem to be able to use this counter concurrently.  I have so far produced the following:

```
ServerProtocol.java

public class ServerProtocol {

private static final int ANOTHER = 2;
private static final int OPTIONS = 3;
private static int yourCounter;

case OPTIONS:
    if (theInput.equals("1")) {
        theOutput = "computer program description here  -- Another? Y or N";

        int tmp = yourCounter;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
             System.out.println("sleep interrupted");
        }
        yourCounter = tmp + 1;

        System.out.println("Download Total " + yourCounter);

        TrackDownloads clientDetails = new TrackDownloads();
        clientDetails.trackLocalhostAddress();
        state = ANOTHER;
case ANOTHER:
```

With the above method, when 2 or clients request the option simultaneously, the *yourCounter* variable only increments once.  I'm expecting that only a single client is granted access to the variable at once to ensure the counter remains accurate.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing your lecturer wanted you to learn about synchronization, or more accurately the use of the synchronized keyword.

Comment: ..also your `DownloadCounter` method `incrementAndGet` should be static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `synchronized` keyword. Each access to the counter should be in a `synchronized` block that locks the same object: either a `static synchronized` method of the class, or a synchronized block that explicitly locks `TheClass.class`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a locking mechanism. Since this is a homework I'd like to point to the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you permitted to use volatiles?

You could always just use some synchronization to get around that.